# Sending some non-encrypted fragments in a PlayReady stream

Tags: drm, smooth-streaming, playready

I have a *PlayReady* protected *Smooth Stream*, which I encrypt manually (by adding the `Protection` element to the client manifest, adding a *Sample Encryption Box* inside each fragment's `traf` box and encrypting the actual `mdat` payload).

I am trying to implement a new feature - send several non encrypted fragments (e.g., ads or first N fragments of the stream) within that stream.

After reading the [PIFF standard by Microsoft](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9682897), I attempted to send non encrypted data by setting the `flags` field to 0x00001, and the `algorithm_id`, `sample_count` and `key_id` fields in the Sample Encryption Box to zeros (As mentioned in section 5.3.2.2 of the PIFF standard).

While trying to play that stream, the sample players I tested (http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/doc/slee/ and player.smooth.vertigo.com/) played the content, but skipped the non encrypted fragments and started directly from the encrypted ones.

Is this feature even possible to implement? Am I doing anything wrong?

P.S., I tried to omit the *Sample Encryption Box* altogether, but that resulted in the players refusing to play the stream entirely.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a sample of such a modified video on a public URL or provide it as a zip file? I would be happy to take a look and try some other PlayReady-supporting players, as well.